# Discrete Math/Combinatorics - Find the probability of selecting exactly one of the correct six integers in a lottery...

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

full question: "Find the probability of selecting exactly one of the correct six integers in a lottery, where the order in which these integers does not matter from the positive integers not exceeding 40"

OK, so I actually figured out what the answer was, but I'm unsure of how it works. Could I get an explanation please?

The answer is:

$\frac{\binom{6}{1}\binom{34}{5}}{\binom{40}{6}}$ = $\frac{139128}{319865}$

The $\binom{40}{6}$ is the total combinations of numbers, and I think the $\binom{34}{5}$ is the total ways to pick the 5 incorrect numbers. What does the $\binom{6}{1}$ mean?

Comment: You choose $1$ of the drawn $6$ numbers. There are $\binom{6}{1}=6$ possibilities to do that. For every possibility, we have $\binom{34}{5}$ possibilities to choose $5$ wrong numbers, so we have to multiply the binomial coefficients

Comment: @Peter Why are we choosing one of the drawn 6 numbers? Are we saying this is the correct draw? (I understand the math here, but I'm not understanding the concept behind it).

Comment: @Peter and we use 34 because we're saying there's a pool of 34 wrong numbers and we're choosing 5 of those, right? I guess I'm still confused on the correct number itself in that case.

Comment: Maybe, a simple example helps. Suppose, $1,2,3,4,5,6$ have been drawn. Then, we have exactly $1$ hit, if we have exactly one of the numbers $1,2,3,4,5,6$ and exactly $5$ of the numbers $7,8,9\cdots,40$. So, we have $\binom{6}{1}$ possibilities for the correct numbers and $\binom{34}{5}$ possibilities for the incorrect numbers.